# Adding string in $("#string")

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have the code:

```
$("#auto").append('<div id="' + results_id + '"></div>');
```

but I want `auto` to be a string:

```
var string="auto";
```

Then I want to use it as:

```
$("\'+string+'\").append('<div id="' + results_id + '"></div>');
```

I don't know why, but this is throwing some error.

Someone hinted me that we must be using escape string so as to use it in this way, but then don't know why, I am without any luck.

Comment: $("#"+string).append("...");

Comment: why not $("#"+string).append('<div id="' + results_id + '"></div>');

Answer (score 1):

do it like this:

```
$('#' + string)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for:

```
var string = "auto";
$('#' + string).append('<div id="' + results_id + '"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery allows you to use variables for selectors without a problem. You just need to remember to call a correct element, so if you call for ID remember to use **#** before your `string` variable value.

```
var string="auto";
$("#"+string).append('<div id="' + results_id + '"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
$('#' + string).append('<div id="' + results_id + '"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have qoutes not correctly nested and also you miss the sharp sign. Maybe try something like this:

```
$("#"+string).append('<div id="' + results_id + '"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
var myString = '#' + MYID;
$(myString).append('<div id="' + results_id + '"></div>');
```

"some explanation"

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please include some explanation in your answers rather than just code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 var string = 'auto';
 $("#"+string).append('THE STRING YOU WANT');
</script>

<div id="auto"><div>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to use jQuery to resolve the symbol itself. And you can create your `<div />` in a nicer way:

```
$(document.getElementById(string))
    .append($('<div />', {id: results_id}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic issue is that you are confusing variable names and their values.

`"#auto"` is a string.

If I declare a variable like:

```
var myString = "auto";
```

then notice that the **variable** `myString` contains the value, `"auto"`.

In jQuery, you can get an element (a div in our example below) to manipulate by calling it with `$("#auto")` - meaning I want the element of the page that has been declared thus on the HTML page:

```
<div id="auto">...</div>
```

But since you can pass a string as an **argument** to the special `$("#")` function so that whatever follows the `#` gets *grabbed* from the page.

Therefore, instead of fixed and pre-determined arguments like `$("#auto")`, you can use `$("#"+myString)` from the example above to achieve the same result, but now by manipulating the value of `myString` you can do lots of things with the same `$("#"+myString)` without bothering about the exact element names over and again.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "auto";
$('#' + string).append(.....);
```

Hope this is the solution for your question.

And can check the below link to know more on selectors.

https://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/9766/jquery-selector-div-variable/p1